# How to run application in background when broadcast is received for wifi each time API to be called

Tags: android, android-service

I am planning to build an application where API is called each time user turn on wifi.

the application is going to have broadcast receiver (local broadcast receiver not global) that is bind to application. The application is going to receive broadcast receiver on wifi connected and then API is going to be called and database is going to store current time stamp.

problem is that what should I use so that application always stays in ram or not but API should be called each time what should I use-  service, work manager or alarm manager or any other suggestion.

thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use WorkManager with WiFi connectivity constraint.

Comment: problem with work manager is that it does not work instantly and I want it to be done instantly.

Comment: Register the `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast then. You might want to do that from a foreground service so that it works when the app is in background. If you do it from an activity it will not work once the app is closed.

Comment: yes I know that .. app closed it will not work thats my question how to achieve this.

Comment: Use a ForegroundService. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services